# Facebook Graph Api - Get Event Type

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to know the event's **type**? For example - party/business/concert...
I think that we could do so at the past - but from some reason I can's find any [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to know the event's type?

There *is* no such thing – not in data field terms.

The user creating an event can put anything they like into the text fields for `name` and `description`. They *might* put the words *“party”* or *“concert”* in there somewhere – but it might as well be something like *“foobar”* instead.

What you make of the content of this fields, is up to you. You could look if any specific keywords are mentioned in there – but I doubt you will be able to classify an event with absolute certainty from that.

Comment: i was expecting facebook to offer such a trivial option like categorize event.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Look for the **category** tag in [https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID](https://graph.facebook.com/361768537237241?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAJ19MxYtX59UzNG5crGpuxFEjbSzpSvQNZBcSjKl2IG4EdOPZBv2sZBgvUdbzj6sS6JEGkA2eNoNZClqQZBNGqSeAML9mkwZDZD)

It seems to be nested under **owner**, so that probably means it describes the owner and not the  event, but it might still be what you're looking for.

Comment: as you said - this type is the owner's type. if the owner is a person it doesn't help :\

Comment: Do you have an example of an event with a type? I tried creating a new event, and I could not choose a type.

Comment: u r right. there's no type field (there was one at the past i think). weird that you can't categorized it

Answer (score 0):

The **category** field is now available as of api v2.4 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event